How to fetch matched audience based on engagement level filter
I have searched but couldn't find any way to do this, My current setup fetches this
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&timeGranularity=DAILY&dateRange=(start:(year:2024,month:1,day:1))&accounts=List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3AXXXXX)&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&projection=(*,elements*(dateRange(*),totalEngagements,viralTotalEngagements,pivotValues*~(localizedName)))&fields=totalEngagements,viralTotalEngagements,pivotValues
I get a list of companies and their engagement, but I can't fetch the audience upload list, so that I can compare to find those who are on the list. it requires dmp_segments permissions, but I can't find the Audience API in my Apps product page.
How can I request the Audience API I need the scopes from that API, and maybe the audience API might provide a way to get matched audience directly without have to request through adAnalytics.
